# Solving equation values

Tags: algebra-precalculus, education

With the equations:

1. $7i_1 - 4i_2 = 50$
2. $12i_2 - 4i_1 = 20$

what is the method finding the values of $i_1$ and $i_2$? Both are integers.
The answers are $i_1 = 10$ and $i_2 = 5$, how was it achieved.

Comment: What are $i_1$ and $i_2$? Real numbers? Integers? You need to provide more information about the problem.

Comment: Yes, they are integers.

Comment: @Redsam121,i1=10 and i2=5

Comment: Yes, I already have the answer. But I want to know how the answer was achieved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply standard elementary algebra methods of elimination. You can divide the second equation by $4$ to get
$$
i_1=3i_2-5.
$$
Then insert into the first equation
$$
50=7(3i_2-5)-4i_2=17i_2-35.
$$
By a lucky coincidence the solution of this is actually an integer.